# Bleak device cant be found on connect but on scan

Tags: python, bluez, raspberry-pi4

Hello i need a little help, im running a raspberry 4 (Ubuntu) with a Logilink BT Stick.

BlueZ is Version: 5.56-0ubuntu4.2

My target is a Xiaomi thermometer which is flashed after https://github.com/atc1441/ATC_MiThermometer

The Connection with gatttool and receive updates work without problems, the device is 2m away from the pi.

I've used the both code listed here:
https://github.com/hbldh/bleak

The first listed Code works and shows me the macs but the second one die every time.

The Connection with gatttool and receive updates work without problems, the device is 2m away from the pie.

Ive used the code listed here:
https://github.com/hbldh/bleak

The first listed Code works and shows me the macs but the second one die every time.

```
 python3 i.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/bt2/i.py", line 13, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(test())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/var/www/bt2/i.py", line 8, in test
    await client.connect(timeout=500.0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/client.py", line 236, in connect
    raise BleakError(
bleak.exc.BleakError: Device with address A4:C1:38:82:8A:50 could not be found. Try increasing `timeout` value or moving the device closer
```

Comment: `gatttool` was[deprecated by the BlueZ](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) project in 2017 as it uses an outdated API to communicate with the Bluetooth hardware. `Bleak` uses the current API that is used the BlueZ tool `bluetoothctl`. Can you connect to the thermometer with `bluetoothctl`? I also suspect that the following example would be better starting point for what you are trying doing: https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/blob/develop/examples/connect_by_bledevice.py

Comment: oh yes i can, https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/blob/develop/examples/connect_by_bledevice.py gives me the services, thank you

Comment: the interesting thing is, its works only when i have bluetoothctl open and did power on and scan on without and with closing the tool the py script don't find the device again.

Comment: That example looks in the list of already known devices rather than doing a scan. If `bluetoothctl devices` doesn't return your device then you need to do a scan first. There are ways to do the `power on` with the Python code but that is probably a new question.

Comment: On a little more investigation, Bleak doesn't only look in the list of known devices. https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/blob/a83283411729f7fa42a68f827efe3cf2285ae03a/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/client.py#L196-L204. `ConnectDevice` requires the BlueZ `bluetoothd` experimental flag to be set. Can be seen with `service bluetooth status`. ConnectDevice is not recommended by the BlueZ project. https://marc.info/?l=linux-bluetooth&m=159013573912327&w=2. It would be good if you could run with logging switched on to see if that gives more details: https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html